# select statement w/ TWO AS aliases?

Tags: sql

I am not a sql master, and this statement just doesnt make sense to me. So if ANYONE could break it down for me and let me know exactly what is what, I would GREATLY appreciate it.

Heres the statement:

```
SELECT a.accountid,a.firstname,a.lastname,a.miName,a.legacyAccountid,a.accountType,
SELECT count(invoices.invID) AS InvCount 
FROM invoices 
WHERE invoices.accountid = a.accountid AND invoices.statusID=0 AND invoices.Remaining>0
AND dueDate < DATEADD(Day,1,GETDATE()) AS AccountStatus,
SELECT count(lotOwnership.lotNumb) AS LotCount FROM lotOwnership WHERE lotOwnership.accountid = a.accountid AS Active
FROM a
WHERE a.accountid LIKE % var % OR a.legAccountid LIKE % var % OR a.lastname LIKE % var % AND a.accountType=1 ORDER BY a.lastname, a.firstname
```

What I would LOVE to know is:

How in the figgin frack is this legit?? Im refering to the whole statement but in particular this nested select:

```
SELECT count(lotOwnership.lotNumb) AS LotCount FROM lotOwnership WHERE lotOwnership.accountid = a.accountid AS Active
```

For some reason I cant wrap my head around this. Somebody please save me! I dont understand how one select statement can have TWO AS aliases???????????????????

Comment: This code is so friggin frackin not legit

Comment: this code does not seem to be right.did you run this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is missing parentheses around the subqueries and quotes around strings:

```
SELECT a.accountid,a.firstname,a.lastname,a.miName,a.legacyAccountid,a.accountType,
(SELECT count(invoices.invID) AS InvCount 
 FROM invoices 
 WHERE invoices.accountid = a.accountid AND invoices.statusID=0 AND invoices.Remaining>0
 AND dueDate < DATEADD(Day,1,GETDATE())
) AS AccountStatus,
(SELECT count(lotOwnership.lotNumb) AS LotCount FROM lotOwnership WHERE lotOwnership.accountid = a.accountid
) AS Active
FROM a
WHERE a.accountid LIKE' % var %' OR a.legAccountid LIKE '% var %' OR a.lastname LIKE '% var %' AND a.accountType=1
ORDER BY a.lastname, a.firstname
```

I did a minimal reformatting of the ugly coding style so you could see where the changes are.  Any idea why these characters are missing?

EDIT:

Consider the first two lines of the `select` (now better formatted):

```
SELECT a.accountid, a.firstname, a.lastname, a.miName, a.legacyAccountid, a.accountType,
       (SELECT count(invoices.invID) AS InvCount 
        FROM invoices 
        WHERE invoices.accountid = a.accountid AND
              invoices.statusID = 0 AND
              invoices.Remaining > 0 AND
              dueDate < DATEADD(Day,1,GETDATE())
      ) AS AccountStatus,
```

The subquery is defined to return a column named `InvCount`.  If you ran it separately, it would have a column with the name `InvCount`.

In this context it is a scalar subquery.  That is, a subquery that returns (up to) one row and one value.  In that context, the returned value is treated as the result of an expression.  So, the column named `InvCount` in the subquery is named `AccountStatus` in the outer query.  You could think of this as:

```
select ((select  . . . ) as InvCount) as AccountStatus
```

Of course, that syntax is not legal, but it captures conceptually what happens.  The first alias is simply ignored.

Comment: ignore the missing characters. this sql code is from a custom vb app. I am simply trying to wrap my head around how its possible that this code has been in production since the apps creation and it does not throw any errors. I JUST WANT TO KNOW HOW ITS POSSIBLE THAT THERE IS TWO 'AS' IN THE NESTED SELECTS STATEMENTS.

Comment: @user2001006 . . . I don't know what you mean.  The code with the correct a parentheses and single quotes doesn't have two `as`s in any statements.  Are you confused that an expression such as `count(invoices.invID)` can be given one alias in a subquery (`InvCount`) and another in the outside `select` (`AccountStatus`).  That is allowed.  The first is simply ignored.

Comment: YES!!! Thats exactly what I am trying to figure out! Please explain more on that! Your are awesome!

Comment: Gordon YOU ARE THE FRIGGIN MAN! I now fully understand this select statement. Thanks everyone who responded in a very quick manner. You guys friggin fracking rock!

Answer (score 2):

The correlated subqueries needed to be surrounded by parentheses. Then, it makes sense because they produce scalar values, which are then aliased with the `AS`.

If your code in the OP runs, then the application must know how to isolate the subqueries without the added parentheses.

```
SELECT 
    a.accountid,
    a.firstname,
    a.lastname,
    a.miName,
    a.legacyAccountid,
    a.accountType,
    (SELECT 
        count(invoices.invID) AS InvCount 
        FROM invoices 
        WHERE invoices.accountid = a.accountid 
        AND invoices.statusID=0 
        AND invoices.Remaining>0
        AND dueDate < DATEADD(Day,1,GETDATE())) AS AccountStatus,
    (SELECT 
        count(lotOwnership.lotNumb) AS LotCount 
        FROM lotOwnership 
        WHERE lotOwnership.accountid = a.accountid) AS Active
FROM a
WHERE a.accountid LIKE % var % 
    OR a.legAccountid LIKE % var % 
    OR a.lastname LIKE % var % 
    AND a.accountType=1 
ORDER BY a.lastname, a.firstname
```